# Return a value from a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, settimeout

I'm trying to return a value calculated in a setTimout. But it seems like I can't do get this value. I read that to do this I must use promises. Am I obliged to use this like this exemple : https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/ ?

My code :

```
renderTeaserBackground = () => {
    return setTimeout(function() {
        this.setState({ teaserAnimCount: this.state.teaserAnimCount + 1 });
        let teaserBackground = teaserBgImg[this.state.teaserAnimCount];
        console.log(teaserBackground);
    }.bind(this), this.state.teaserAnimDuration * 1000);
    return 'teaserBackground';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the page you link to *inside* the question.

Comment: the second return statement is unreachable, it will never execute

Comment: Yes, the good link : https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/#usage

Comment: I think that was the point @ltamajs, he is not sure how to perform a valid return from the async block

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Promise!

### ES6 way - *Standard Promises*:

```
renderTeaserBackground = () => new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
        this.setState({teaserAnimCount: this.state.teaserAnimCount + 1});
        let teaserBackground = teaserBgImg[this.state.teaserAnimCount]
        res(teaserBackground) //Return it here!
    }, this.state.teaserAnimDuration * 1000);
})
```

To use this outside, you can do:

```
const mainLogic = _ => {
    return renderTeaserBackground().then(teaserBackground => {
        /* Use teaserBackground as you need! */
    })
}
```

### ES7 way - *Harmony `async`/`await`*

```
const mainLogic = async _ => {
    const teaserBackground = await renderTeaserBackground()
    /* Use teaserBackground as you need! */
}
```